# How to sort numbers in PHP on given command line argument values?

Tags: php

I'm trying to sort numbers on given command line argument as  `sortnumb$ php phpsort.php 2 5 3 8`and it should print as 2 3 5 8. I have tried following code but I don't know how to save given arguments in an array to use "sort" command in PHP. please advice

```
$argv[1] 
$numbers = array($argv[1]);

sort($numbers);

$arrlength=count($numbers);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
  {
  echo $numbers[$x];
  echo "\n";
  }
```

Comment: Can not replicate the problem. https://3v4l.org/SZ8ar

Comment: I have amended the code .. please check it now appreciate

Comment: Your update makes no sense

Comment: How can I save these values in to an array ? sortnumb$ php phpsort.php 2 5 3 8

Comment: As I said it makes no sense. You had an array, then edited to a syntax error that is just..  odd. I have no clue what you are trying to do

Comment: let me explain you please... just explain me if I execute  sortnumb$ php phpsort.php 2 5 3 8 on command line, and I need to save these numbers in an array and print them in order. How can I do that please ignore example code ..

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site. You should learn some basics first. Command line or not make co difference here.

Comment: I will not ignore the code. That is a important part of SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$argv` contains the array of numbers that you are passing, but `$argv[0]` contains the script name. You can read about [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) in the PHP manual.

So you can take out the array items you are interested in, using [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$numbers = array_slice($argv, 1);
```

The second parameter says to slice from the second item of the index.

Then the rest of the code is correct as you had it.

Although you can use a `foreach` loop instead (read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)):

```
sort($numbers);

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
   echo $number."\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

the argument already saved at $numbers array
you can use $numbers variable to do whatever you want

Comment: it is an example ... I need to know how to save passed 2 3 5 8 values in to an array in php ?

Comment: sorry, i can't understand you, you want to save passed values into array?
it's already saved at $numbers and if you want to save it into another you could do that $newArr = $numbers;

Comment: Basically I need to know how to save argument values in to an array? sortnumb$ php phpsort.php 2 5 3 8 , I need to save these numbers in an array in order to use sort command.

Comment: $numbers = array(2,3,5,8);

Answer (score 0):

You can make array using the **' '** (space delimiter) and then use any of the sorting function on that array